# The "/" at the end of a url

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I found an interesting thing I don't know how to solve:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'my_app1.views.index', name='index'),
    url(r'^path1/path2/', 'my_app1.api.method1')
    // or url(r'^path1/path2', 'my_app1.api.method1')
)
```

I don't want the urls to contain "/" at the end.

If I go to `http://localhost:8000/path1/path2` it redirects me to `http://localhost:8000/path1/path2/` with the "/" at the end. Whatever I do to get rid of the "/" at the end of the url, I fail at. It seems there's no way to do so, unlike in Rails. Is it true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can control it using [`settings.APPEND_SLASH`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash).

By default, it's True. Change the value to False in the project settings file.

```
APPEND_SLASH = False
```

But if you set it, accessing the page `/path/path2` will result 404 error. You need to change the url pattern:

```
url(r'^path1/path2/?', 'my_app1.api.method1')  # To match url with/without trailing /
```